# Daemonize scheduled thread pool

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a daemon in Rust which runs a process on a schedule forever:

```rust
use scheduled_thread_pool::ScheduledThreadPool;
use std::time::Duration;

let pool = ScheduledThreadPool::new(1);
pool.execute_at_fixed_rate(
    Duration::new(5, 0),
    Duration::new(5, 0),
    move || do_business_logic(),
);
```

This stops the threads as soon as processing reaches the end of `main()`. How can I keep it running forever?

Comment: thread will always stop at the end of a program, you maybe want to fork ?

Comment: I don’t see anything in scheduled-thread-pool to join a job or the pool, which seems like an oversight? But you should probably wait on SIGTERM or something and do a cleanup anyway, which will also fix this.

Comment: "How can I keep it running forever?" -> `loop { }`

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Busy wait is really not a good solution to this.

Comment: @Ry- thus I left a comment instead of an answer.  It's _a_ solution that leaves more to solve for

Comment: @Ry- well given that the point of `scheduled-thread-pool` is to repeat jobs indefinitely at regular intervals, there is not much point in a `join` function.

Comment: As a developer, I would expect `ScheduledThreadPool` to have a method `run` which just blocks forever. Implementation could be, that it calls `join` on all worker threads. This way the programs exits, if all threads died.
If the pool restarts threads, that have died, that could be done in the main thread too, so it even has some work to do.

Comment: @typetetris that makes sense to me. I can't find a crate that has such functionality though.

Comment: @Steve I assumed you are writing that `scheduled_thread_pool` thing yourself, and wanted to hint at making its API like that.

Comment: @typetetris nope, it's the crate `scheduled-thread-pool` which was the only thing I could find to schedule tasks to run on a schedule.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `loop { }` suggested in the comments.

This has drawbacks:

- it will burn cpu needlessly
- your program will run forever, even in the case your `do_business_logic()` panics.

Lets look at the docs of `scheduled_thread_pool::execute_at_fixed_rate`, it says under Panics:

> If the closure panics, it will not be run again.

That doesn't sound very helpful, if you want to notice in your program, wether your `do_business_logic` panics

So you could create a `std::sync::Channel` and just wait for receiving a value on the channel.

You move the sender into the closure you hand over to the thread_pool.

If your closure panics, the sender will be dropped, and the receiver will stop waiting. So you know, something happened.

Some working code:

```
use scheduled_thread_pool::ScheduledThreadPool;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::mpsc::*;

fn main() {
    let pool = ScheduledThreadPool::new(1);
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<u8>, Receiver<u8>) = channel();
    let killswitch = std::sync::Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(false));
    let killswitch2 = killswitch.clone();
    pool.execute_at_fixed_rate(
        Duration::new(5, 0),
        Duration::new(5, 0),
        move || {
            if *(killswitch2.lock().unwrap()) {
                panic!("gotto go!");
            }
            println!("haha");
            tx.send(1).unwrap();
        }
        );
    for (count, _) in rx.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("got one");
        if count > 0 {
            println!("that's boring, killing it");
            *(killswitch.lock().unwrap()) = true;
        }
    }

    println!("Have a nice day");
}
```

clippy yelled at me for using a `Mutex` around a `bool` and suggested using an `AtomicBool` instead, but I think, that is a different rabbit hole.

Comment: *“This has the drawback, that your program will run forever, even in the case your `do_business_logic()` panics.”* It also has the significant drawback that it burns CPU time doing nothing for no reason, which really makes it not worth mentioning as an option at all, IMO.

Comment: Yes. I should change my answer. Will do when not on mobile.

Comment: So, answer edited. Don't burn cpu.